# Removing total days from Hhh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a varchar field that stores a duration for connections that occasionally goes into the days. I'm trying to separate the total number of days from the hh:mm:ss in this field so I can store them separately but I'm getting an out of range error whenever I try to convert this data to any type of datetime variation in order to datepart the days from the value and then deduct. Is their any way of doing this or will I need to resort to a crude charindex(':' just to remove the days?

Comment: What is the format of your varchar exactly?

Comment: 305:19:43 which is hhh:mm:ss.  It's in a varchar(1024) field but I'm reducing the fields by making each individual time/int/bigint and so fourth.  the hhh:mm:ss is this particular duration I call "Duration1" and that's what I've parsed out of the text field.  Technically these are ASA SNMP messages with a lot more but that's the parsed data that I'm having trouble with, everything else is working out fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to chop it up since it's not in a valid date or time format:

```
DECLARE @timeString VARCHAR(50) = '114:48:50'
SELECT   Day_CT = LEFT(@timeString ,CHARINDEX(':',@timeString )-1)/24
        ,Tm = CAST(CAST(LEFT(@timeString ,CHARINDEX(':',@timeString )-1)%24 AS VARCHAR(12))+STUFF(@timeString ,1,CHARINDEX(':',@timeString )-1,'') AS TIME)
```

This is one of the many reasons why dates and times shouldn't be stored in string data types, it makes using them ugly.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but thanks for including the SELECTs for that, much appreciated.  The STUFF function is new to me so I will have to investigate some additional best practices for that function.